# Batch script to move files from one location to another except one file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script to move files from one location to another.Which works fine.But when I want to exclude one file from it, there comes the issue.

I have the following files in folder XYZ:

```
ABC_2017.qvd
ABC_201701.qvd
ABC_201702.qvd
ABC_201703.qvd
ABC_201704.qvd
ABC_201705.qvd
ABC_201706.qvd
```

I want to move all the files from this XYZ folder from input path to a folder WXY in Output path.(I have created variables for the paths)

```
move %Input_Path%\XYZ\ABC_2017*.qvd %Output_Path%\WXY
```

Doing this is moving all the files including `ABC_2017.qvd`. But I want to exclude `ABC_2017.qvd` from moving.

I tried this but it does not work

```
move %Input_Path%\XYZ\ABC_2017*.qvd %Output_Path%\WXY /exclude:%Input_Path%\XYZ\ABC_2017.qvd
```

What can I do?

Comment: Use [ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead.  You can use the `/XF` and `/MOV` options.

Comment: Hi, First 2 options did not work. 3rd option worked but in the XYZ folder I have ABC_2016.qvd,ABC_2015,qvd,ABC_HIST.qvd   and it is moving all the .qvd files in the folder except ABC_2017 I want to keep the 2015 ,2016 and HIST file along with the ABC_2017 .qvd

Comment: Any files you do not want processed you can use the /XF option to exclude them from processing.  You can use wildcards with the exclude.

Comment: This one works: ROBOCOPY "%Input_Path%" "%Output_Path%\WXY" /MOV ABC_2017*.qvd /XF ABC_2017.qvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROBOCOPY` as [@Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) said:

```
ROBOCOPY "%Input_Path%\XYZ" "%Output_Path%\WXY" /MOV /XF ABC_2017.qvd
```

---

This should work, too:

```
FOR %%G IN ("%Input_Path%\XYZ") DO (
    IF NOT "%%~nxG"=="ABC_2017.qvd" MOVE "%%G" "%Output_Path%\WXY"
)
```

This will move every file if its name and extension does not equal `ABC_2017.qvd`.

Comment: Your first approach cannot work, because `?` matches zero or one characters if placed at the end, even before `*`...

Comment: You should update your answer to use the file mask in the `FOR` and `Robocopy` solutions.